# Use casperjs , phantomjs & slimerjs (headless browser) in firefox addon sdk

Tags: firefox-addon, phantomjs, firefox-addon-sdk, casperjs, slimerjs

Is it possible to use a headless browser in firefox addon sdk ? or is there a way to use casperjs , phantomjs & slimerjs in addon code ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you can package the PhantomJS executable or the Slimer.js executable into an addon, then yes, it would be possible.

Comment: Please guide me on how to do that @ArtjomB.

Comment: Is this for use in a html file? If you are making an html/xhtml file you can do whatever you do on a normal website.

Comment: No i want to open a webpage and do operations without a visible interface. For example : Hitting the "like" button of the first image i find in my facebook feeds without opening facebook in browser.